Cannot download pdf file in Swagger with content-type application/pdf
I have an endpoint done with Express in which I download a pdf file as buffer, setting:
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=download.pdf')

Using Postman, everything works fine, and pdf is downloaded correctly.
Now, I'm trying to generate documentation using Swagger, and I would like to download the file in the swagger, as I can do in postman. The Swagger json file I wrote is as follows:
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "it should return a binary",
    "content": {
      "application/pdf": {
        "schema": {
           "type": "string",
           "format": "binary"
        }
      }
    }
  }
...

But when I execute the swagger, and error happens:
Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text.

And the binary info is displayed in swagger:

But when I change the application/pdf to application/octet-stream both in express application and the swagger file, a download file button appears and I can download the file, although it is neccessary to add the file extension to .pdf after download it.

Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I followed instructions according to swagger documentation (Response That Returns a File), and everything looks so simple that I'm beginning to think there's some kind of bug. I read several post in stackoverflow  related, but nothing worked for me.

If your API server uses CORS, make sure the response includes the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header with the value Content-Disposition:
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition

This will make the Content-Disposition response header actually visible to Swagger UI.
